# Controller undefined after generation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Just started using Phoenix and I generated the project and ran phoenix.gen.json Todo todos description:string

/lib/test_web/router.ex

```
# Other scopes may use custom stacks.
      scope "/api", TestWeb do
        pipe_through :api

        resources "/todos", TodoController, except: [:new, :edit]
      end
```

/web/controllers/todo_controller.ex

```
defmodule Test.TodoController do
  use Test.Web, :controller

  alias Test.Todo

  def index(conn, _params) do
    todos = Repo.all(Todo)
    render(conn, "index.json", todos: todos)
  end
end
```

And a GET to /api/todos gives a 500 - ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function TestWeb.TodoController.init/1 is undefined (module TestWeb.TodoController is not available)

Comment: Should not the controller module be named `TestWeb.TodoController`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Same error

Comment: You have explicitly restricted `POST` to this url in your router, why would you ever expect it to work?

Comment: @mudasobwa GET doesn't work either the controller is undefined

Comment: How do you run the application?

Comment: mix phx.server in the CLI

Comment: Why do you use legacy generator `phoenix.gen.json` _and_ modern server `phx.server`? You should use the same modern version of the generator ([`phx.gen.json`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Json.html#content).)

Comment: Can you change your question to reflect the changed to the module name, and give an updated error, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your router and your controller are expecting two different parent modules for your controller. You have the router looking for the controller under 'TestWeb' (see the scope), but your controller says it's 'Test.TestController' not 'TestWeb.TestController'.

One solution would be to change `scope "/api", TestWeb do` to `scope "/api", Test do`.

Another option would be to change `defmodule Test.TodoController do` to `defmodule TestWeb.TodoController do`.

It's really a matter of preference (though sticking to the generator's convention might be nice).

Answer (score 0):

Use the same modern version of the generator (phx.gen.json). Old generator was defining modules outside the scope of the project.

Working after switching to the new generator.